# To read windows registry using a C++ program on Windows 7

Tags: c++, registry, key

I want perform a couple of basic operations on windows registry. I wrote a small C++ program to read current user key. Below is the code snippet. I am honestly not sure why RegOpenKeyEx() isn't returning ERROR_SUCCESS. Please advice.

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    HKEY hkey;

    if(RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, TEXT("SoftwareDevShed TutorialTest"), 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hkey) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        cout<<"Error opening the key"<<endl;
    else 
        cout<<"Success"<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Does the key exist? What is the return code...

Comment: Yes the key exists. The return code is 2.

Comment: Well 2 is `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`... So presumably the key does not exist.

Comment: Try checking the GetLastError() value.

Comment: @ViktorLatypov `RegOpenKeyEx` returns a status code http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724897(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where have the backslashes gone here: `TEXT("SoftwareDevShed TutorialTest")`?
Shouldn't that read `TEXT("Software\\DevShed Tutorial\\Test")`?

Comment: thanks very much. backslashes was the problem. I am new to windows registry programming is there a good document on the internet which explains registry programming in C.

Comment: @user1428522:  The MSDN is your resource.

Answer (score 1):

The TEXT() macro indicates that the key might be opened using the Unicode version.

Try the

```
RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "<your correct Key name with backslashes>", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hkey)
```

Comment: Why check `GetLastError()`? The documentation says the function returns a status code, nothing more. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724897(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    DWORD dwType;
    char  szVersion[255];
    DWORD dwDataSize = 255;
    memset(szVersion, 0, 255);

    // open the key for reading.
    HKEY hkeyDXVer;
    long lResult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "SOFTWARE\\Software Nmae\\", 0, KEY_READ, &hkeyDXVer);

    if(ERROR_SUCCESS == lResult)
    {
       // read the version value
       lResult = RegQueryValueEx(hkeyDXVer, "RegistryValue", NULL, &dwType, (BYTE*)szVersion, &dwDataSize);
       if(ERROR_SUCCESS == lResult)
       {
          std::cout << "Value - " << szVersion << std::endl;
       }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This Code works perfectly on all versions of windows.

Comment: got these errors............m:\vs 2008\registry reading\registry reading\read registry.cpp(13) : error C2664: 'RegOpenKeyExW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char [24]' to 'LPCWSTR'
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
m:\vs 2008\registry reading\registry reading\read registry.cpp(18) : error C2664: 'RegQueryValueExW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char [14]' to 'LPCWSTR'
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast